# Unity3d multiple bools work like toggle on a button press

Tags: unity-game-engine, boolean, toggle

I have three bools in a script boolA, boolB & boolC.
At start boolC activates. Bools are working fine in inspector but i want to connect them to a "Button" like:
If button pressed 1st time then "boolA" activates and boolB and boolC deactivates.
If button pressed 2nd time then "boolB " activates and boolA and boolC deactivates.
If button pressed 3rd time then "boolC" activates and boolA and boolB deactivates.
AND
if button pressed again after 3rd time then again "boolA" activates.
Here is my code

```
public bool a = false;
public bool b = false;
public bool c = false;

void Start () {

    c = true;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (a == true) {
        if (c)
            c = false;
            a = true;

    }

    if (b == true) {
        if (a)
            a = false;
            b = true;
    }

    if (c == true) {
        if (b)
            b = false;
            c = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: well you are cycling round every frame so that would be a bit hit and miss, so you wouldnt want it  in update

Comment: There is no need of having all 3 bool's stored separately as they're logically interconnected. You should use some sort of container, even a simple array

Answer (score 0):

First of all move your script to OnClick event to work only when you click your button.

```
void OnClick() {

if (a == true) 
{
    b = true
    c = a = !b;
}

if (b == true) {
    c = true
    b = a = !c;
}

if (c == true) {
    a = true
    c = b = !a;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here are states so I would not use `bool` for this but rather e.g. an `enum` like

```c#
public enum ButtonState
{
    A, // == 0
    B, // == 1
    C, // == 2


    count // not used as value but simple way to wrap around the maximum value
}
```

and then do

```c#
// initially it is C
ButtonState currentState = ButtonState.C;

public bool a = false;
public bool b = false;
public bool c = false;

public void OnButtonPressed()
{
    var index = (int)currentState + 1;
    if(index >= (int)ButtonState.count) index = 0;

    currentState = (ButtonState)index;

    // Now if you really need those bools
    a = currentState == ButtonState.A;
    b = currentState == ButtonState.B;
    c = currentState == ButtonState.C;

    // otherwise use the currentState e.g. with a switch
}
```

The big advantage here is that if you later decide to add more possible states you only need to add these to the `enum` before `count` and wouldn't have to make the changes everywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks but getting errors. The name `State3' does not exist in the current context
The name `a' does not exist in the current context
The name `b' does not exist in the current context
The name `c' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I would think State3 implied ButtonState.C. For the rest, you need the variable declarations if you were to use the booleans. Not all the code is to be used. Either first 3 lines or other 3 lines. If you use the enum, no need for booleans

Comment: Yeah sorry refactoring on the phone ;) it should have been `ButtonState.C`. and we'll `b` etc would obviously be your bool fields you already have ...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the most clarity would have the following code. I'm writing it in Answer's editbox, so please excuse if I've made any mistakes as I don't have my back cover by the compiler.

```
private bool b[] = new bool[3] { true, false, false };
private int curr;

public void OnButtonPressed()
{
    curr = (curr + 1) % b.length; // here we are moving from one element 
                                  // to the next and back to the first one when 
                                  // we encounter the end

    for(int i = 0; i < b.lenght; ++i) // and here we're simply setting all your bools up
        b[i] = i == curr;
}
```

It's easy to understand and very concise. Even more, if you need another state, so that you'd have 4 of them, you simply have to change the number of elements in `b` array.